# TypeError: Cannot read property 'blogCategory' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

**Im having issues when trying to render blogpost from json file in React**

```
const BlogPost = (props) => {

    const [post, setPost] = useState({
      id: "",
      blogCategory:"",
      blogTitle:"",
      postedOn:"",
      author:"",
      blogImage:"",
      blogText:"",
    });
    const [slug, setSlug] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
      const slug = props.match.params.slug;
      const post = blogPost.data.find(post => post.slug == slug);
      setPost(post);
      setSlug(slug)
    }, [post, props.match.params.slug]);

  return(
        <div className="blogPostContainer">
          <Card>
            <span className="blogCategory">{post.blogCategory}</span>
            <h1 className="postTitle">{post.blogTitle}</h1>
            <span>posted on {post.postedOn} by {post.author}</span>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
   )
  }


export default BlogPost
```

```
json:

{
    "data" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "blogCategory": "Featured",
            "blogTitle" : "Fitness Mantra To Live Fit Life",
            "slug": "fitness-mantra-to-live-fit-life",
            "postedOn": "July 21, 2016",
            "author": "Faiz Khan",
            "blogImage": "fitness-blog-post.jpg",
            "blogText": "Midst first it "
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "blogCategory": "Simple",
            "blogTitle": "Beautiful & Special Moment",
            "slug": "beautiful-and-special-moment",
            "postedOn": "May 03, 2016",
            "author": "Rizwan Khan",
            "blogImage": "beautiful-&-simple.jpg",
            "blogText": "Extremity "
        }
    ]
}
```

I've added the Json file it pull the information from at the top.

comes up with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'blogCategory' of undefined", even though I've initially made useState as an array pleas help!

Comment: Where is the blogPost object coming from? I don't see it being a prop.

Answer (score 0):

This use effect seems to be faulty. It should cause an infinite loop unless the *post* is always the same value. It probably means that the post is *undefined* (as the error says) so it must mean that there is no post with the given slug, I would check those values, also might want to change the post.slug == slug to post.slug === slug.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const slug = props.match.params.slug;
  const post = blogPost.data.find(post => post.slug == slug);
  setPost(post);
  setSlug(slug)
}, [post, props.match.params.slug]);
```

This state is obsolete inside the given component, it is not used anywhere (assuming this a full code of the component) so it could be removed.

```
[slug, setSlug] = useState('')
```

There are two solutions to your issue, considering that `props.match.params.slug` will eventually hold a valid slug and won't endlessly be undefined/empty/null.

First one is wrapping the `setPost` with a *undefined* check like this. Please note I've removed the obsolete `setSlug` here. I've also removed post from the dependency array as it could lead to infinite loop and is non-required here. I've also added a dependency for `blogPost.data` in case it has some empty initial data.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const slug = props.match.params.slug;
  const post = blogPost.data.find(post => post.slug == slug);
  if (post) {
    setPost(post);
  }
}, [blogPost.data, props.match.params.slug]);
```

The other solution is to add optional chaining for the `post` object and updating the `useEffect` like follows. I've also fixed dependency list for the same reason as for the previous approach.

```
const BlogPost = (props) => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const slug = props.match.params.slug;
    const post = blogPost.data.find(post => post.slug == slug);
    setPost(post);
  }, [blogPost.data, props.match.params.slug]);

  return (
    <div className="blogPostContainer">
      <Card>
        <span className="blogCategory">{post?.blogCategory}</span>
        <h1 className="postTitle">{post?.blogTitle}</h1>
        <span>posted on {post?.postedOn} by {post?.author}</span>
      </Card>
    </div >
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Its attached to a json with the correct values, when I console log post it returns the object

Comment: Could you paste the content of the blogPost object?

Comment: What slug are we looking for?

Comment: the slug is the title of each blog article, idea being it generates all of the slugs in the json, when clicked loads that particular object

Comment: I meant what is the value in props.match.params.slug, so we can check whether it actually is in the list.

Comment: so when I console log it, it comes as undefined. I believe the issue is before react can get to the useEffect it need slug to equal something, which is why I put useState to be ('') initially but some reason it  doesn't recognise this

Comment: That's because your `const slug` inside useEffect overshadows it. That wouldn't help with the issue anyway as there is no post with empty slug. I think that wrapping setPost with a check for undefined could fix your problem.

Comment: Ah ok ive tried various options but i cant get it to render correct after; i've tried: if( slug == undefined) return null; but just doesn't render anything

Comment: Did you at any time got anything different than undefined from "props.match.params.slug"?

Comment: yeah it didn't get the undefined error, but it didn't load anything either

Comment: I've updated the answer with a pair of fixes. Please let me know what value is stored by the `props.match.params.slug` for each render.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issue in your code except extra invalid code tag of `</div>` inside `<Card>`

Invalid Code

```
<div className="blogPostContainer">
          <Card>
            <span className="blogCategory">{post.blogCategory}</span>
            <h1 className="postTitle">{post.blogTitle}</h1>
            <span>posted on {post.postedOn} by {post.author}</span>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
```

correct code

```
<div className="blogPostContainer">
          <Card>
            <span className="blogCategory">{post.blogCategory}</span>
            <h1 className="postTitle">{post.blogTitle}</h1>
            <span>posted on {post.postedOn} by {post.author}</span>
          </Card>
        </div>
```